# Read from PDF and display on console

Tags: java, file, pdf, io

I tried reading from PDF file and display it on console but it displays some weird characters not sure what is it. I need to read from PDF file and display it on the console. here is my code

```
public class JavaApplication14 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("F:\\abc.pdf");
        char[] temp = new char[10000];
        fr.read(temp);

       System.out.println(temp); 

    }

}
```

Comment: What should be the output of your program?

Comment: From documentation: `FileReader is meant for reading streams of characters`. Pdf files are binary so you cannot expect to read them these way.

Comment: When you open a video file this way, do you expect the subtitles to come up as argument to println() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a library for properly reading PDF documents. [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) and [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) are examples.

The weird output is because the content is binary: it also contains fonts, images, colors, metadata...

Comment: in PDFBox, look for PDFTextStripper. https://pdfbox.apache.org/cookbook/textextraction.html

Answer (score -1):

You will need itextpdf lib for this example. Just download it and put it into lib folder of your project.

```
public class GetPDFContent {

    public static String reader(String filename) throws IOException {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filename);

        pageNum = reader.getNumberOfPages();
        for (int i=1; i< pageNum; i++) {
           String page = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, i);
           System.out.println(page);
        }       
    }
}
```